# Scala loops with multiple conditions - what gets returned?

Tags: scala

I'm going through scala for the impatient and came across an example of the multi condition loops that I can't seem to understand.

Coming from Java background I'm looking at these loops as nested for loops. But why does the first return a `collection` and second a `String`?

```
scala> for (i <- 0 to 1; c <- "Hello") yield (i + c).toChar
res11: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char] = Vector(H, e, l, l, o, I, f, m, m, p)

scala> for (c <- "Hello"; i <- 0 to 1) yield (i + c).toChar
res12: String = HIeflmlmop
```

Comment: See http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html

Comment: In short, with for-comprehensions the return type is determined by the first collection (or traversable) used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for comprehensions are just syntax sugar and are translated into invocations of `map`, `flatMap`, `withFilter` (also `foreach` if you don't use yield).

```
for {
  i <- 0 to 1
  c <- "Hello"
} yield (i + c).toChar
```

is equivalent to

```
(0 to 1).flatMap(i => "Hello".map(c => (i + c).toChar))
```

These transformers are defined in a way that they return the same type of collection they were called on, or the closest one, for example here `Range` becomes a `Vector` in the end as you can't have `Range` that contains arbitrary characters. Starting from `String` you still can have `String` back.

In general you can think of it like this: result type created by for comprehension will be same as the type of the first generator (or closest possible).

For example if you convert string into a `Set`

```
for {
  c <- "Hello".toSet[Char]
  i <- 0 to 1
} yield (i + c).toChar
```

you will get a `Set` back, and because it is a set it will not contain duplicates so the result is different. `Set(e, f, m, I, l, p, H, o)`

The way how type is determined involves the `CanBuildFrom` trait. You can read more about how it works [here](http://blog.bruchez.name/2012/08/getting-to-know-canbuildfrom-without-phd.html)

Comment: Another way to do your example with `Set`: `for { _ <- Set(' '); c <- "Hello"; i <- 0 to 1 } yield (i + c).toChar`. Not sure it's a better way, but sometimes it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Use scala 2.11.8 repl for desugar (press tab after print, remove`<pressed TAB here>`):

```
scala> for (i <- 0 to 1; c <- "Hello") yield (i + c).toChar //print<pressed TAB here>

scala.Predef.intWrapper(0).to(1).flatMap[Char, scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char]](((i: Int) => 
    scala.Predef.augmentString(scala.Predef.augmentString("Hello").
        map[Char, String](((c: Char) => i.+(c).toChar))(scala.Predef.StringCanBuildFrom))))(scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq.canBuildFrom[Char]) // : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char]

scala> for (i <- 0 to 1; c <- "Hello") yield (i + c).toChar //print
res4: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char] = Vector(H, e, l, l, o, I, f, m, m, p)

scala> for (c <- "Hello"; i <- 0 to 1) yield (i + c).toChar //print<pressed TAB here>

scala.Predef.augmentString("Hello").flatMap[Char, String](((c: Char) => scala.Predef.intWrapper(0).to(1).
        map[Char, scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char]](((i: Int) => i.+(c).toChar))(scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq.canBuildFrom[Char])))(scala.Predef.StringCanBuildFrom) // : String

scala> for (c <- "Hello"; i <- 0 to 1) yield (i + c).toChar //print
res5: String = HIeflmlmop
```

More readable output:

```
scala> (0 to 1).flatMap(i => "Hello".map(c => (i+c).toChar))
res14: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char] = Vector(H, e, l, l, o, I, f, m, m, p)

scala> "Hello".flatMap(c => (0 to 1).map(i => (i + c).toChar))
res15: String = HIeflmlmop
```